# I want to read data from a text file via StreamReader, edit a specific string and write it to the file vis StreamWriter

Tags: c#, streamreader, streamwriter

I want to read data from a text file via StreamReader, edit a specific line, and write it to the file (not append the strings but update it) via StreamWriter.

I have already created the file and populated it with strings. The following code is just to edit a string from that file.

The code runs smoothly but it doesn't update the data. It just lets the string as it is in the file.

```
var path=@"C:\sample.txt";
StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
using (StreamReader read=new StreamReader(path))
{                
     var line = "";
     var fields = line.Split(',');
     while (!read.EndOfStream)
     {
         line = read.ReadLine();
         fields = line.Split(',');
         if (fields[0] == txtAccountNumber.ToString())
              data.AppendLine(fields[0] + "," +
                              fields[1] + "," +
                              account.Balance.ToString());
         else
              data.AppendLine(line);
     }
read.Close();
} 

using(StreamWriter write=new StreamWriter(path))
{                
    write.WriteLine(data);
    write.Flush();
    write.Close();
}
```

Comment: The code `txtAccountNumber.ToString()` looks suspicious. If `txtAccountNumber` is a winforms textbox then you should write `txtAccountNumber.Text`. Msdn: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.text?view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Forms_TextBox_Text

Comment: Thank you so much. That was the problem.

Comment: I overlooked that part

Comment: Weird. How did it even compile?

Comment: Good eye @mortb, just from the object name, impressed!

Comment: I don't know but the code did run without any error.

Comment: All classes inherits from `object` which has the `.ToString()` method. If the class doesn´t have its own implementation the default implementation in `object` will be used. The default implementation will output the type name of the class. I´ve made this error myself :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. I forgot to put .Text in the txtAccountNumber.ToString()

```
var path=@"C:\sample.txt";
StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
using (StreamReader read=new StreamReader(path))
{                
     var line = "";
     var fields = line.Split(',');
     while (!read.EndOfStream)
     {
         line = read.ReadLine();
         fields = line.Split(',');
         if (fields[0] == txtAccountNumber.Text.ToString()) //*Point of error
              data.AppendLine(fields[0] + "," +
                              fields[1] + "," +
                              account.Balance.ToString());
         else
              data.AppendLine(line);
     }
read.Close();
} 

using(StreamWriter write=new StreamWriter(path))
{                
    write.WriteLine(data);
    write.Flush();
    write.Close();
}
```